# How to make frequency table with specific class in R

Tags: r, cut

I want to make a frequency table with matrix "b", which has 100 observations.
I'm trying to make all observations are cut into 15 classes, so that for example the frequency table should include some 'empty classes' that no observations are included.

However, when I use function table(), classes(or levels) are included whose observations are not empty. ( 12 levels)

How can I force them to have 15 levels?

```
> b <- matrix(as.matrix(b),ncol=1)
> fivenum(b)
[1] 24.2 24.7 24.9 25.1 25.6
> bcut <- seq(from = 24.2, by =0.1, length.out = 16); bcut
[1] 24.2 24.3 24.4 24.5 24.6 24.7 24.8 24.9 25.0 25.1 25.2 25.3
[13] 25.4 25.5 25.6 25.7
> bgroup <- factor(cut(x = b, breaks = bcut, include.lowest = T))
> levels(bgroup)
[1] "[24.2,24.3]" "(24.3,24.4]" "(24.4,24.5]" "(24.6,24.7]"
[5] "(24.7,24.8]" "(24.8,24.9]" "(24.9,25]"   "(25.1,25.2]"
[9] "(25.2,25.3]" "(25.3,25.4]" "(25.4,25.5]" "(25.6,25.7]"
```